# How do I migrate release updates from one org to another?

Tags: release-update

If I have release updates in one org, can I retrieve this in sfdx metadata format to migrate this and deploy to another salesforce org?
Is there any specific Metadata API file which I can retrieve?

Should it be manual process to enable test run?

I created a scratch org, enabled there a test run

[image]

and tried to run `sfdx force:source:pull` but nothing has been pulled in my sfdx project.

I expected there to be some `ReleaseUpdateTestRun` metadata item or `ReleaseUpdateSettings` metadata item but I see nothing.

Is this even possible to enable dry run by leveraging Metadata API or sfdx deployment or is this something that require manual UI click for enablement?

Comment: What do you mean by "release update"? As in an official Salesforce update, such as a platform update from Summer '23 to Winter '24?

Comment: no, test runs...

Comment: I have updated my question to include a screenshot

Answer (score 2):

No, it is not possible to retrieve and import these settings. The `ReleaseUpdateTestRun` is not a supported metadata type for any of the major developer-related APIs, as seen on the [Metadata Coverage Report](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/60) page.

You should enable those manually within setup in the org.